# Jackson deserializes object from JSON in reversed order

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Jackson is deserializing the JSON elements in reversed order of what I get. We have an environment where we have a frontend that sends something like the next JSON:

```
{
    "nameElement": "element",
    "subElementList": [
        {
            "nameSubElement": "a"
        },
        {
            "nameSubElement": "b"
        },
        {
            "nameSubElement": "c"
        }
    ]
}
```

And a backend that deserializes it through Jackson to objects like this:

```
@Entity
public class Element {

    private String nameElement;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "element", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @SortNatural
    private SortedSet<SubElement> subElementList;

}
```

```
@Entity
public class SubElement {

    private String nameSubElement;

}
```

The problem comes when we look at the database, where the subElements of the list are deserialized and saved in the reversed order: element c would be id 1, element b would be id 2, and element a would be id 3, but we need exactly the opposite, since the order of the frontend is the opposite. I tried to change SortedSet by List but it didn't work.

Comment: `Jackson` for [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) uses [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) implementation. By default your `SubElement` class should implement `Comparable<SubElement>` interface to make it work. So, order depends from the order you have implemented in `compareTo` method. If you need the order in which element came from frontend you need to use `List` instead. See [example how to](https://www.concretepage.com/hibernate-4/hibernate-4-sortcomparator-and-sortnatural-example-for-sortedset-mapping) .

Comment: Of course I implement compareTo (all of these classes extend from a basic class and there's where the compareTo is), but as I said, changing SortedSet by List didn't work either

Comment: I created simple `POC` which shows that `Jackson` creates `List` in incoming order and `SortedSet` in order specified by `compareTo` method. It must be related with other layers of your app which is not shown here. Could you create [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `Comparable` interface and provide implementation for `compareTo` method interface as `@SortNatural` uses sorting with `Comparable implemented by entity.

Comment: All my classes extends from a basic class where compareTo is implemented, but that's not the problem cause when I change SortedSet by List it doesn't work either.

Comment: Then check your compareTo, sorting order is decided by this only